# Javascript will not combine these together

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, formtastic, jtextarea

I have this js code

```
elem=$(this);
var tester_names="";
tester_names=$("#release_tester_tokens").val();
alert(tester_names)
if (elem.attr('checked')==true)
  **tester_names=tester_names+", "+ elem.attr("title");**
  alert(elem.attr("title"))
  alert(tester_names)
```

I want to have tester_names=tester_names+", "+ elem.attr("title"); to have the combination of testers_names (a,b,c,d,e) and elem.attr("title") (f) to become (a,b,c,d,e,f)
The alerts that I used is for debugging to see what values are stored in the variable.. They all store correctly, but they don't combine together when I call the bolded function... I just want to know why. I am using formtastic textarea instead of the normal textbox... do I have to adjust to that? Or maybe what the tester_names and elem.attr are outputting are of different type?

I tried it using this type of code (this is nearly the same with different variable names

```
function updateTextArea() {     
  var allVals = [];
  $('.taglist :checked').each(function(i) {

     allVals.push( $(this).val());
  });
  $('#video0_tags').val(allVals).attr('rows',allVals.length) ;

  }
  $(function() {
    $('.taglist input').click(updateTextArea);
    updateTextArea();
  });
});​
```

why does this add to checkbox values to the textarea perfectly whenever I check checkboxes when mine just outputs same results before and after using the starred function?

(I don't understand why ppl keep voting this down... its seems like a decent question after the first mishap and fix) :S

Comment: "combine the two together" ... what does that mean?  Combine the two *what* together?

Comment: Based on the indentation, it looks like you're missing some braces.

Comment: `{` and `}` are your friends. They will not bite.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: because he's using alerts, it doesn't look like the braces would do much.  He's probably just got that in there for debugging.  Instead of only firing when the condition is true, it'll fire every time, which isn't necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: nevermind, I hadn't read his statement... now I'm *confused*

Answer (score 1):

Use `elem.attr('checked')=='checked'` in if statement. There is no case `elem.attr('checked')==true` will be true. So the body of your if , will never be executed.

Comment: It'd be better to use `elem.prop('checked')` because the property is always a simple boolean.

Comment: @Pointy better still to use `this.checked`.

Comment: +1 for understanding what he was talking about: I think this is what he was looking for ~ a way to concatenate `tester_names` and `attr('title')`